# sentencia PDO solo se ejecuta en una pagina

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Hola amigos de StackOverFlow soy nuevo con las consultas en PDO tengo una duda al momento de representar los datos en archivos diferentes. Veran cuando hago una conexion y hago una consulta en un mismo archivo la consulta se ejecuta perfectamente. Muestro el codigo de la pagina

//Mi archivo unico pdo.php <-- imprime los resultados sin problemas

```
  <?php

  define('USER' ,'root');
  define('PSD', 'toor');
  define('SERVER', 'localhost');
  $db= 'mydb';
  $srv= 'localhost';

  try {

        $dsn= "mysql:host={$srv};dbname={$db}";

        $dbh= new PDO($dsn,USER,PSD);

        echo  'conectado'; 

  } catch (PDOException $error ) {

     echo $error->getMessage();
  }


       $query= $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM productos ");
       $query->execute();

       while($row = $query->fetch()) {

            echo $row['title'];
            echo $row['descripcion'];

       }

   ?>
```

En este archivo donde tengo la conexion y hago la consulta e imprimo los datos me los muestra sin problemas, el problema esta cuando tengo los archivos separados mis paths son

#Paths representativos

- /controls/config.php
- /controls/connect.php
- /views/index.php <-- aqui intento ver los datos sin un resultado satisfactorio :,v.

//Mi archivo controls/connect.php

```
<?php

  define('USER' ,'root');
  define('PSD' ,'toor');
  define('DB' ,'mydb');

  $db= 'mydb';
  $srv= 'localhost';
  ?>
```

//Mi archivo controls/config.php

```
<?php
 ini_set('display_errors', 1);
 include_once("connect.php");

 try {
      $dsn= "mysql:host{$srv};dbname={$db}";
      $dbh= new PDO($dsn, USER, PSD);
      echo 'conectado'; 

 } catch (PDOException $e) {
         echo $e-> getMessage(); 
 }
```

?>

//Mi index views/index.php
Aqui solo me muestra el mensaje de conectado por lo cual no tengo problema en mi conexion
ni en los archivos pero por alguna razon no me visualiza los datos >:v.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../bootstrap.min.css">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

 <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-dark bg-primary">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler d-lg-none" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-     target="#collapsibleNavId" aria-controls="collapsibleNavId"
    aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation"></button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapsibleNavId">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto mt-2 mt-lg-0">

        <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" href="views/index.php">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">carrito</a>
        </li>
       
    </ul>

  </div>
</nav>

<div class="container">

  <div class="alert alert-success">
        sucess mensaje
        <a href="" class="badge badge-success ">ver carrito</a>
  </div>

  <div class="row">

    <?php 
    
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    include_once("../controls/connect.php"); 
    include_once("../controls/config.php"); 
   
     //prepara los datos para ser ejecutados
       $query= $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM productos ");
     //ejecuta la consulta 
       $query->execute();


       while($row = $query->fetch()) {

            echo $row['descripcion'];
       }

       //$listaProductos= $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
       //print_r($listaProductos);
    ?>

    <div class="col-3">

        <div class="card">
            <img class="card-img-top" src="../item0.jpeg" alt="descripcion producto"   width="200" height="360">
            <div class="card-body">
                <span>titulo producto</span>
                <h4 class="card-title"> $price</h4>
                <p class="card-text">descripcion producto</p>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="btnAccion" value="agregar">agregar carrito</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        
    </div>

</div>
```

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.10.2/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-7+zCNj/IqJ95wo16oMtfsKbZ9ccEh31eOz1HGyDuCQ6wgnyJNSYdrPa03rtR1zdB" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js">  </script> 
<script src="../bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Eh intentado de todo pero no se porque no muestra la informacion si en realidad es el mismo codigo solo que lo tengo en rutas diferentes y siento que por ahi va el problema pero no doy con la solucion para mi desdicha humana :,v , tampoco me muestra algun error en el codigo
lo que en teoria esta "bien" mi codigo. >:v

Comment: En tu ejemplo veo algunas veces ```define('USER' ,'root');``` y otra ```define('USER' ,'toor');```, quizás el problema va por allí.

Comment: Hola amigo gracias por responder en realiadad el codigo es el mismo solo que lo edite aqui por cuestiones de practicidad segun yo jaja xD define('PSD', 'toor')  es para el password

Comment: Creo ya se por donde va el asunto, ahora intente agregar mejor la sentencia  y el while en mi archivo config.php hago un echo en el index y me muestra [Notice: Trying to access array offset on value of type bool in pathX/index.php ] lol xD

Comment: Hay un error importante en el archivo **config.php** línea 6. En la parte `...mysql:host{$srv};...` falta un signo de `=`, debe ser: `...mysql:host={$srv};...`.

Comment: hola amigo gracias revisando el codigo lo observe igual saludos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hola amigos ya encontre la solucion a mi desdicha humana temporal, resulta que el problema era mas sencillo de lo que pensaba, estaba mal escrito mi codigo que raro xD.
para ser mas exacto y no repetir codigo es esta parte de mi archivo config.php

```
  //faltaba agregar el igual a '=' xDDD 
  dsn= "mysql:host{$server};dbname={$dba}";
  //como debe de estar escrito xD
  dsn= "mysql:host={$server};dbname={$dba}";
```

Una vez que agregue el signo de asignacion me funciono el codigo sin problema, doy por solucionado mi problema nos vemos!.